# How do you get a Vout of 2.29 in the simulation with a differential opamp and a wheatstone bridge?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, multisim, wheatstone-bridge, pt100

I made a circuit to read the resistance of a PT-1000 (a platinum RTD [Resistance Temperature Detector] of 1 kΩ at 0°C) and I know I messed something up with the linearity; whatever I try, I can not get a Vout of 2.29 V.

[image]

Comment: That doesn’t look like a differential op amp to me

Comment: (R1+R2) or (R2+PT) are reversed. To work, both inputs MUST BE at the same voltage

Comment: Since that sim HAS 2.29V, presumably it's not what you built. What did you build and what opamp did you use? Did you check the input voltage range and output voltage swing for your choice of opamp? Come to that, you told us what your output isn't, bu not what it is...

Comment: _ to measure PT1000_. Please edit your question and explain in plain English what "PT1000" means.

Comment: I misread the PT value. This looks OK. What did YOU get instead of  2.29 V?  @DavideAndrea I just read the PT is a platinum RTD of 1k at 0'C  But the question assumes we are mind readers in how he messed up.

Comment: Thank you Tony. I will edit OP's question and spell out what a PT 1000 is. Davide

Comment: I really appreciate your time and responses. Sorry for my inconvenience. A pt1000 is  Platinum Resistance Thermometer. It is possible to measure the temperature depending on the resistance of the PT1000. Depending on the resistance value, it calculates the temperature. Example 1000 ohm is 0 °C. But because the arduino can not measure the resistance, it is solved with a wheatstone bridge where you get the voltage. But the voltage value is to small and the idea is to amplifiy this value with the MCP6002 opamp. But i cant manage the same result as the simulation shows.

Comment: What temperature would you measure (scale)? What output voltage would you want? Note that sensitivity is "maximum" when all the resistors are equal.

Comment: Hello Antonio, thank you very much for your response. So i thougt if i use the voltage devider formula for the lines PR1 and PR2, i would get respectively 0.608 V and 0.454 V. Then i would substract them and multiply it by the gain. Vout = (0.608-0.454)*((10k/ 909.09)+1) =  1.84 V. Then there is the voltage offset of the opamp that is max. 4.5 microvolt.  I had like to a range between 0 and 100 °C. I just want to prove, my calculations are the same with te simulation.

Comment: @Emperium in your voltage-divider calculations you've failed to account for the fact that R5 loads the PR1 (R1,R3) divider - so you do not have 0.454V at that node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your circuit, reproduced in CircuitLab. The simulator gives a result of 2.299V at Vout.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f67WjT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The error in your calculations starts where you "voltage devider formula for the lines PR1 and PR2" - because the "PR1" leg consisting of R1 & R3 is also affected by R5, and you haven't accounted for that.

Here's a slightly modified version of your circuit which makes it easier to see what's really going on:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4ITfd.png)</sup>

It also produces 2.299V at Vout - because *it's effectively the same circuit*.
In your original circuit, you calculate the PR1 voltage divider value as if it's un-loaded, with no current flowing in or out of the divider through R5.
What I've done in my modified version is to model your voltage divider as a voltage source *with a source impedance*, using Thevenin's theorem to calculate the source impedance I show here as PR1 (which is simply your R1 in parallel with R3).

So now you can look at this circuit as a fairly straight-forward non-inverting amplifier with a gain of 12 and an offset of 0.4545V

So to calculate the output, we take your correctly calculated value for PR2 (0.608V), subtract the offset (0.454V) giving us 0.154V, then multiply by the gain (12) producing 1.848V, and then add the offset (0.454V) back in -> leading to a result of 2.302V, which is only slightly off from the simulator's result due to the rounding errors in our calculations here.

Comment: Dear brhans, I really really thank you this was a wonderfull clear answer. God bless you and I wish you all the good things in the world. Just a little question, in the datasheet it is stated that there is input offset with a max 4,5mV. Should I add that to the Vout too?

Comment: Only if you're trying to calculate what the possible error range could be at your output. The datasheet shows that the input could be anywhere between -4.5mV and +4.5mV, and that offset could be on either of the inputs or both of them.

Comment: Oke understood, again I thank you kindly for your time and responses.